# ¿Como exportar una base de datos de mysql a acces?

Tags: mysql

Me gustaría saber como hago para poder importar desde Access una base de datos de Mysql. Es para un trabajo y he mirado pero no he encontrado cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Para importar una tabla de Mysql a Microsoft Access, desde Access, y con la base de datos en la que se quieren importar los datos abierta, seleccionar el menu Archivo->Obtener datos Externos->Importar. En la pantalla de Importar datos, en la opcion Tipo de archivo seleccionar ODBC databases(). pones la ruta de la base de datos y te importas los registros con un par de clicks

espero funcione

salu2

Comment: Sii amigo si me funciono, Muchas Gracias!!